# MySQL: How to perform an action if a unique field is already used with INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, unique

I'm using the MySQL statement INSERT INTO to insert data into my table. I have several unique fields such as username and email. I want to insert data, but if a unique field is already taken (say somebody tries to use an already existing username) I want to perform an action.

Say redirect the page, or set a session. At the moment my code just acts like it inserts, but then obviously does nothing as the field is unique. I've tried the belowcode but I'm having no luck.

```
// Add the data to the table 'users'
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users
(username, password, email, dob, gender) VALUES('$username', '$cleansedPassword', '$email', '$dob', '$gender') ")
or header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;

header( 'Location:  SignUp.php' ) ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well I have not worked on returning error from mysql but if mysql query is not true it will return the error....  you can use that to check whether it is actually added or error returned and in case of error - you can redirect accordingly - it will take 2 more statements rather then just one line statement. but that is right way as i far as I know

Answer (score -1):

mysql_affected_rows — Get number of affected rows in previous MySQL operation

If the number of affected rows is zero, you know that the insert statement didn't work.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users
(username, password, email, dob, gender) VALUES('$username', '$cleansedPassword', '$email', '$dob', '$gender')");

if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0){
     header( 'Location: index.php' )
}else{
     header( 'Location:  SignUp.php' )
}
```

Comment: How would I use this in the code? ; If (mysql_affected_rows) == 0 { start session }?

Comment: This is wrong since the query will FAIL if the constraint has produced an error and function will return -1, not 0. The proper way is to check whether the query succeeds or not, not to check affected rows.